# Cannot print on HP Smart Tank 515

Tags: windows-7, printer, print-spooler

I purchased HP smart tank 515 device . Trying to run it on windows 7 64 bit sp1 Installed all drivers from

ST510_Full_WebPack_48.3.4531.exe downloaded from HP  site . Connected the device via Usb connection

On "devices and printers" section - I see that device installed successfully

But when I'm trying to print test page - I got error :

**Test page failed to print..**

Scanning works properly.

What can cause to the issue and how it can be resolved ?
Which setting(s) should be checked additionally ?

Checking in parallel on HP site but did not find solution yet

Thanks in advance

UPD : some addition when trying to print from Notepad - Got error 
**A StartDocPrinter call was not issued.**